# this.props.*** is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to this React Redux thing.

I was trying to replicate the same tutorial from Traversy Media Youtube channel
Github: https://github.com/bradtraversy/lead_manager_react_django

and encounter some problem with this.props.function

I have tried reading around the Stackoverflow but I was not using mapDispatchToProps and I don't really understand it as I am trying to understand the tutorial

Music.js

```
export class Music extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
      musics: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
      getMusics: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.getMusics();
  };}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  musics: state.musics.musics
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, {getMusics}
)(Music);
```

I stripped the rendering part because I haven't implemented

types.js

```
export const GET_MUSICS = "GET_MUSICS"
```

actions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

import {GET_MUSICS} from './types';

export const getMusics = () => dispatch => {
    axios.get('/api/musics/').then(res => {
        dispatch({type: GET_MUSICS, payload: res.data});
    }).catch(err=> console.log(err));
}
```

reducer musics.js

```
import {GET_MUSICS} from '../actions/types.js';

const initialState = {
    musics: []
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_MUSICS:
            return {
                ... state,
                musics: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

This will throw the error this.props.getMusics is not a function
console.log(props) return empty object

Comment: Since you are exporting both, the class itself and the connected component, it might have happened that you accidentally imported the class itself and not the connected component. How are you importing the Music class?

Comment: I import it ```import {Music} from "./Music"``` which is pointed out in the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting  `Music` both as named export and default export. Make sure to use the default export because that is connected to store. i.e do this,

```
import Music from "./Music"
```

and not this,

```
import {Music} from "./Music"
```

Comment: This is actually the problem! I was confusing about ```import``` and ```import{}``` but I think it won't cause troubles any soon. Will keep an eye on this!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help u try this

```
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'

...

function mapDispatchToProps(state) {
    return {
        musics: state.musics.musics
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return bindActionCreators({fetchMusics}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Music)
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification on how to use mapDispatchToProps. But the problem underlying was the import from outside component.

Answer (score -1):

pls check the parent component you might not be passing the function correctly,also more code is required showing the parent component

Comment: yeah Music.js file path is src\components\layout\Body\Music.js and it's included in Body.js which included in App.js